Invalid principal in policy while creating policy for AWS s3 and AWS Polly
I have been struggling to find out the error in writing the principal correctly. From Aws console I am trying AWS polly and want to save the output to s3 bucket. The IAM user is created with the following permissions:
{
    "AttachedPolicies": [
        {
            "PolicyName": "AdministratorAccess",
            "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess"
        },
        {
            "PolicyName": "AmazonPollyFullAccess",
            "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonPollyFullAccess"
        },
        {
            "PolicyName": "AmazonS3FullAccess",
            "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess"
        }
    ]
}

On S3 Bucket permission tab I trying to add the given policy:
{
  "Id": "Policy1720073611620",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1720071547531",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mytest2-text-to-speech/*",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "polly.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}


Where did you get this syntax? I couldn't find any reference to a bucket policy that grants access to a principle of polly.amazonaws.com. When I read Setting up the IAM policy for asynchronous synthesis - Amazon Polly it seems like the IAM User should have the permission, rather than granting access to the Polly service.

Thanks for the help. I have fixed the issue.

Great to hear you fixed it! If you think your solution would be useful for other readers, you are welcome to post your own Answer. Or, if it was related to some other problem, you are welcome to Delete your Question if it won't assist future readers.
